# Merge rows in pandas dataframe and sum them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe as below:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| First | some date |
| first | some date |
| FIRST | some date |
| First | some date |

How can i merge the rows as they basically are same thing

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| first | count of all rows containing first,First,FIRST |

result would be

| Name | count |
| --- | --- |
| first | 4 |

basically I want to count all rows with similar string using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```py
df.groupby(df.Name.str.lower()).count()
```

Output:

```py
       Name  Date
Name             
first     4     4
```

After that you can select the columns that you want like `['Date']`.

In this case:

```py
df.groupby(df.Name.str.lower()).count()['Date']
```

Output:

```py
Name
first    4
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It's better to slice before aggregation to avoid the useless computation on other columns ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
len(df[df['Name'].str.lower() == 'first'])
```

Try this it will compare column values by making them to lowercase with the particular string and will let you know the final length.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer from @99_m4n , just posting the full code:

```py
import pandas as pd


datadict = {'FIRST': 'some data', 'first': 'some data', 'First': 'some data', 'FirsT': 'some data'}

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({'Name': list(datadict.keys()), 'Date': list(datadict.values())})
    .assign(Name=lambda x: x["Name"].str.lower())
    .groupby(['Name']).agg({'Date':'count'}))
df
```